# Multiple image sliders in HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html

Please help. This div and script works only once. I want to separate slideshows one after the other ,with different images. But if I try to write this script more than once the slideshow doesn't work. I tried everything I can. The div and the script works fine when it comes to a page with only one age slideshow.but when it's more than one it doesn't.

```
<div >
  <img alt="kandy" src="kandy4.jpg" style="width:1000" 
height="500" class="kandy">
  <img alt="kandy" src="kandy.jpg" style="width:1000" 
height="500" class="kandy">
  <img alt="kandy" src="kandy2.jpg" style="width:1000" 
height="500" class="kandy">
  <img alt="kandy" src="kandy3.jpg" style="width:1000" 
height="500" class="kandy">
</div>
<script>

var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("kandy");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 3 
  seconds
}
</script>
<div >
  <img alt="ella" src="ella4.jpg" style="width:1000" 
height="500" class="ella">
  <img alt="ella" src="ella.jpg" style="width:1000" 
height="500" class="ella">
  <img alt="ella" src="ella2.jpg" style="width:1000" 
height="500" class="ella">
  <img alt="ella" src="ella3.jpg" style="width:1000" 
height="500" class="ella">
</div>
<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var j;
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("ella");
    for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
       y[j].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
   if (myIndex > y.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    y[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 3 
seconds
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood the question but perhaps the following might be of use? A slightly simplified layout from the orginal but same content - except for changes made to the `style` attribute which was incorrect.

If the `carousel` function accepted arguments then you can call it many times with different arguments - as it was a later calling would like overwrite the previous invocation of the function.

```
<div>
  <img alt="kandy" src="kandy4.jpg" width='1000px' height='500px' class="kandy">
  <img alt="kandy" src="kandy.jpg" width='1000px' height='500px' class="kandy">
  <img alt="kandy" src="kandy2.jpg" width='1000px' height='500px' class="kandy">
  <img alt="kandy" src="kandy3.jpg" width='1000px' height='500px' class="kandy">
</div>
<div>
  <img alt="ella" src="ella4.jpg" width='1000px' height='500px' class="ella">
  <img alt="ella" src="ella.jpg" width='1000px' height='500px' class="ella">
  <img alt="ella" src="ella2.jpg" width='1000px' height='500px' class="ella">
  <img alt="ella" src="ella3.jpg" width='1000px' height='500px' class="ella">
</div>

<script>
    /* pass in whatever class as an argument */
    const carousel=function( _classname, _index, _time ){
        let col=document.getElementsByClassName( _classname );
        Array.prototype.slice.call( col ).forEach(function(e){
            e.style.display='none';
        });


        if( _index > col.length - 1 ) _index=0;
        col[ _index ].style.display='block';
        console.info( col[ _index ] );

        setTimeout( function(){
            carousel.call( this, _classname, _index, _time );
        },_time * 1000 );

        _index++;
    }

    carousel('kandy',0,3);
    carousel('ella',0,3);

</script>
```